# Firefox printing cuts canvas on end of first page, how do I make it not do that?

Tags: css, image, firefox, google-chrome, printing

http://fiddle.jshell.net/bTtKT/show/

If I print the above page in Chrome as A4 Landscape I get two pages as expected given the size of the canvas on the page, if I do the same in Firefox however (with print preview for example), it gives me only one page and therefor cuts the image/canvas in half. If I change the scale in Firefox however I do start to see the whole image (but then it's too small), so the image is there as a whole but Firefox seams to ignore that its bigger then one page for some reason.

How do I get Firefox to recognize that the image needs more then one page so I can print the whole thing in correct size?

(possible to edit the above page example here: http://jsfiddle.net/bTtKT/ )

Comment: Did you ever solve this? I'd be interested to know :-)

Answer (score 0):

I didn't try it out, but you could try:

```
canvas { page-break-inside: avoid; }
```

See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/page-break-inside

Comment: Tried it but it doesn't seam to work, the canvas still brakes.

Answer (score 0):

Putting this style on the div encompassing the canvas might help ya:

```
page-break-inside: avoid
clear: both
float: none
```