# Firefox not printing complete image(canvas/png) if the height of the image in greater than print page height

Tags: javascript, html, image, firefox, printing

If I try to print an image whose height is equivalent to 3 A4 size pages then firefox prints only first page (i.e printing only 1/3rd of the image) but if same image I print in chrome, it will be printed completely on three pages.

I found one [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10350688/firefox-printing-cuts-canvas-on-end-of-first-page-how-do-i-make-it-not-do-that) but its not working.

One way I found is to break the image manually into the parts equal to the pages required to print it completely.
The solution for cutting image using js I found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8912917/cutting-an-image-into-pieces-through-javascript#answer-8913024)
But again there is one problem: The size of A4 page is 8.27 × 11.69 inches, now while cutting the image I need to give size in pixel which will be dependent on the screen's PPI or print DPI.

How to break image to multiple pages when height is greater than the print page in firefox?